# Why the sticky footer is not working on Samsung smartphone Note 2, built in browser?

Tags: android, html, css

I am using sticky footer design for my website that I have adopted from Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS3 (second edition) from Ben Frain. It is working perfectly on major modern browsers but not on Samsung Galaxi Note 2 built-in browser. I am wondering why? .Any explanation or advice is welcome, including any feedback from iphone users.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<title>Sticky footer</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#header{
    background-color: #0FF;
}
#MainContent{
    flex: 1;
}
#footer{
     background-color: #0F9;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="header">This is the header</div>
<div id="MainContent">This is the main content</div>
<div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "my phone being samsung"... What model of Samsung phone? What browser do you use on there? According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) older versions of the android stock browser still need `-webkit-` prefixes for flexbox. Please update your question.

Comment: can you take screenshoot from your phone and let me see how its showin

Comment: Apparently the built-in browser in Samsung Galaxi Note 2 is not working as the footer appear at the top. However based on comment from @ahmdabos I tried to find out which other browser is available on Samsung Galaxi Note 2. I just found chrome. Chrome renders the sticky footer correctly. Is there any other browser available for Samsung Galaxi Note 2, such as FireFox which is my favorite browser?

Comment: I just found that FireFox renders correctly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung Galaxi Note 2, in-built browser, does not handle html5 flexbox concept properly even by putting -webkit. Use Chrome or FireFox instead.